# Elias Zakon, Chapter 1, Excercise 15, Operations on Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a proof via idempotent/commutative/associative/distributive/Morgan's duality laws to the following equation?:
$$A-B=A\cap - B$$

Thanks,
Vlad

Comment: For $\LaTeX$, you must put '$' on both sides of what you want to format.

Comment: Thank you, it took me some time time to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't; we need, at some point, the definition of the "set minus" operation:

By definition, alone, we have set equality:

$$x \in A - B \iff (x \in A \land x \notin B) \iff (x \in A \land x \in \lnot B) \iff (x \in A \cap \lnot B)$$

Hence, we have $A - B = A \cap \lnot B$

---

Comment: I have considered the proof by definitions, thank you for the attempt.  However, that is not the question.

Comment: Your answer is no. What you've written is, by definition, true.

Comment: @amWhy: This needs a TU! +1

Comment: Just for my friend, Amy :+)

Answer (score 0):

No, at least under (what I believe to be) the usual meaning of the laws you listed. The reason is that those laws don't mention the binary operation of subtraction (though de Morgan's laws do mention complementation). To get a proof of your equation, you'd have to add something characterizing subtraction.  My inclination would be to add the definition of subtraction, namely $A-B=A\cap-B$, but that obviously trivializes your question.

Comment: Thank you Andreas,  I would love to consider both yours and amWhy's answers as accepted, however, after amWhy's correction, it looks more complete now.  Only one answer can be accepter, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false, so the answer must be no.  Do you mean $A-B=A\cap \lnot B$?  Isn't that the definition of $A-B$?

Comment: I cannot, as I do not own the book and do no wish to sign up at that site.  Present your definitions.  Surely the question looks like a standard statement about sets; it is easy to come up with a counterexample.  Did you copy the question correctly?  Perhaps there is an error in the book?  What is your definition of $A-B$?  It is not up to us to find a book that you cite.

Comment: I would like to present the definitions at full, but the nature of the comment section prevents me from doing so: there's simply not enough character budget to fit the definitions and required mark-up characters.  Can you suggest a better way of achieving that? As for the rest of your question: as far as I know, there's no error in the text that I am referring to.  The only definitions related to a possible definition of A-B that I may think of at this point are:  $$A-A=\emptyset$$ and $$A-\emptyset=A$$

Comment: If you don't even know what $A-B$ means, how could you begin to prove something about it?

Comment: I believe this question has been covered by the excellent answers from amWhy and Andreas Blass.